# customize the authentication mechanism in Typo3 4.5

Tags: authentication, typo3

I have to customize the authentication mechanism in a Typo3 4.5 project. I've been looking since yesterday on the source code responsible for authentication, but I couldn't find it. Does someone know where it is ? maybe a function, a class ??

thanks in advance

Comment: Backend or frontend?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the the sys-extension "felogin", there are all references you need to build your own login. It is located at `typo3/sysext/felogin`.